VCPKG: create & use local registry instead of remote
Currently I use cmake + vcpkg configured under manifest mode to query a remote registry (defined in vcpkg-configuration.json) for package dependency. It works fine for a first run - packages have been built/installed under "vcpkg_installed" folder. I also noticed that there are UUID folders containing vcpkg.json and portfile.cmake for the packages under folder %APPDATA%/local/vcpkg/git-tree.
Now I would like to freeze a few packages' versions and there is really no need to query the remote registry every time the code is rebuilt. But it seems that every time a rebuild is triggered, vcpkg will always first try to query the remote registry as part of the work flow, only to report that "all required packages have been installed" in the end. If I remove the remote registry, it will complain about missing package versions etc.
To stop this querying behavior, given that the package info is already downloaded into git-tree folder, how can I create a local registry to have vcpkg query it instead and still resolve to "all required packages have been installed"?
Following the example here, I got "internal error: ...\commands.add-version.cpp: vcpkg has crashed; no additional details are available" at step 4 "Update the versions database". Each port folder are directly copied from git-tree with the UUID renamed to port name.
I also noticed under git-tree there is another folder with baseline.json and folders with name "a-", "b-" etc. containing dependent packages for the ones I would like to redirect the query (to the local registry I am creating). I suppose it's vcpkg generated, but wonder if I can make use of this.
Thank you.

Did you encounter any issues when using the above mentioned approach? I think you can also set variable VCPKG_MANIFEST_INSTALL to OFF when running cmake to avoid vcpkg from updating existing dependencies

Got an error with no useful info, please see edits. Also I would need manifest mode as it contains configs for a majority of the other packages used/built. I am just trying to change the registries querying for a few packages here.
